# How do I get object and not address without using String/ toString?

Tags: java, string, overriding, tostring

I need to create my own `String` class called `MyString` without using default String class/vector API. I have to work on some required methods, and their return types are predetermined. I can add other methods as long as `String` is not used.

Expected use would be:

(at main) `System.out.println(str.toLowerCase())`  - returns lower case of str

When I want to work with `toLowerCase()` method with return type `MyString`, I can't return the object content but only return the address.

Normally, this problem would require modification of `toString()`, but since this method requires return type of String by default, I can't use modification of `toString()` for the assignment.

The assignment is supposed to be not so hard and should not require complex extensions. My constructor may be the problem, but I can't specify which part is.

**Code**

```
public class MyString {
private char value[];

MyString(char[] arr){
    this.value = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
}

... 

MyString toLowerCase() { // can't change return type
    for (int i =0; i<value.length; i++) {
        if ((int)value[i] > 64 && (int)value[i] < 91) {
            value[i] = (char) (value[i]+32);
        }
    }
    return this; // this returns address, and I can't override toString
}
```

Comment: The only way to interact with the internal Java classes is through the specified API - `toString` is part of that API. There is **no other** way to describe how you want to print your class as a `String`. You could consider adding a `PrintWriter` Decorator - a `MyStringPrintWriter` that uses some method to take a `MyString` and output it to `char` by `char`.

Comment: @aka-one why? `MyString` can be mutable. `String` being immutable doesn't affect a custom implementation.

Comment: @aka-one not sure I understand your point. The mutability or immutability of a classes affects how it is shared. This doesn't affect what methods need to be implemented, only _how_ they are implemented. If you want to write your own string class, you're going to have to reimplmenet all the methods either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with `System.out.println(str.toLowerCase())` is it ends up calling `PrintStream.println(Object o)`, but that method internally at some point calls `o.toString()` which uses code inherited from `Object#toString()` (since you couldn't override `toString` as it expect as result `String` which is forbidden in your project) which result in form `TypeInfo@hexHashCode`.

This means you can't use `System.out.println(MyString)`.

BUT `PrintStream` (which instance is held by `System.out`) allows us to provide data to print in different forms. In this case you can use [`println(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-). All you need to do is adding to `MyString` method like `toCharArray()` which would return (preferably a copy of) array of characters held by `MyString` class.

This way you can use it like `System.out.println(myStringInstance.toCharArray())` so code from your `main` method would need to look like

```
System.out.println(str.toLowerCase().toCharArray());
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^--this should return char[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `String` class is an immutable type, i.e. the methods of `String` do not change the internal state (i.e. the `char` array), instead they return a new instance of type `String`.
To mirror that behavior you could implement something like this:

```
public MyString toLowerCase() {
    char temp = new char[value.length];
    // [...] Your code performing the actual logic on temp
    return new MyString(temp);
}
```

The immutability (and its implications) of the `String` class is very important to understand in practice. For example, the following code procudes the intended result:

```
String word = "Word";
System.out.println("I can produce upper case (" + word.toUpperCase() + ") " + 
                   "and lower case (" + word.toLowerCase() + ") " + 
                   "without any side-effects on the original (" + word + ").");
```

However, it's not possible (without "hacky" solutions) to implement a method like this:

```
void shortenString(String inputAndOutput);
```

Second, the assignment expects that the class/method must be used as follows:

```
System.out.println(str.toLowerCase());
```

The attribute `out` is effectively a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), which offers (besides other methods) the following two:

> `println(Object x)` - Prints an Object and then terminate the line.
>
> `println(String x)` - Prints a String and then terminate the line.

If the method is called with an `Object` parameter, the internal implementation calls `toString()` on the given object, thus the only way to satisfy the requirement is to override this method. Unfortunately, this is not allowed by the assignment.

However, if it is not explicitly stated that the solution has to use `java.lang.System`, you could simply implement your own `System` class which accepts `MyString`, e.g.:

```
public class System {
    public static class MyPrintStream /* optional: extends PrintStream */ {
         public void println(MyString x) {
             java.lang.System.out.println(x.getCharArray());
         }
    }

    public static final out = new MyPrintStream();
}
```

This would allow you to use it exactly as described in the assignment:

```
import my.package.System;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // [...] Instantiate str
        System.out.println(str.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: While `String` is immutable, there is no hint that his own `MyString` class has to be immutable too.

Comment: I assume that the main purpose of this assignment is to understand the concepts and internals of the `String` class and one _very important_ concept is the immutability.